# Как создать ListView c мульти-выбором, который отображался/скрывался по нажатию кнопки

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox

activity_main.XML

```html
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".list.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="http://" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="+"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:onClick="add"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="-"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:onClick="remove"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

list_item_multiple_choice.XML

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ctvRss"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd" />
```

В коде написано следующее:

```js
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item_multiple_choice, rsss);
rssList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Не получается именно скрыть/показать CheckBox по нажатию кнопки.

Answer (score 0):

Я вижу два варианта: динамическое создание вашего `ListView` на вашем макете, либо просто при нажатии кнопки показывать и скрывать этот виджет. Как динамически добавить элемент вы можете прочитать [здесь](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/addview.php). Либо есть более простой на мой взгляд вариант. В `android` есть такая прекрасная функция, как `View.INVISIBLE` это вы скрываете ваш список, но тем не менее может быть использован для ваших задач, либо есть функция `View.GONE`. Более подробно вы можете почитать [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556607/android-difference-between-invisible-and-gone). Надеюсь хоть чем-то вам помог в вашей проблеме. Удачи :)